# Swift String hasSuffix Error

Tags: linux, string, swift

String.hasSuffix does not seem to be working in Swift 2.2-dev on Linux, in a script. It works in the REPL. What am I missing?

> cat hasSuffix.swift

```
import Foundation
let vegetable = "red pepper"
print(vegetable.hasSuffix("pepper"))
```

> swift hasSuffix.swift

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '_TFE10FoundationSS9hasSuffixfSSSb' which could not be resolved!
```

> swift -version

```
Swift version 2.2-dev (LLVM 46be9ff861, Clang 4deb154edc, Swift 778f82939c)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Someone suggested I compile the script using swiftc. This produces an executable named "main". The executable runs without error and prints the expected message. This suggests that there is a bug in the interpreter? I am new to Swift, just going through the examples in "Welcome to Swift".

Comment: It was me. I deleted it because it was not a complete solution and I wanted to test more before answering. // Yes, your script works once compiled with `swiftc`. No idea why it doesn't run with `swift`.

Comment: I've finally made an answer after running some tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Alternative

The `swift` command is indeed confused for some reason by your script, but the same script works once compiled with `swiftc`:

> $ swiftc hasSuffix.swift
>
> $ ./hasSuffix

#### Debugging

`swiftc` is actually just a link to the `swift` executable.

But the `swift` app is able to tell if it's been launched with `swift` or `swiftc` and behaves differently.

We know that with `swiftc` it launches the compiler and with `swift` it either launches the REPL or compiles a script "on the fly".

Using `-driver-print-jobs` as an option for `swift` and `swiftc` we can see the differences between the "compiler" mode and the "on the fly" mode:

> $ swift -driver-print-jobs hasSuffix.swift

It prints the actual command that was launched:

> .../swift/usr/bin/swift -frontend -interpret hasSuffix.swift -target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -disable-objc-interop -color-diagnostics -module-name hasSuffix

Now with `swiftc`:

> $ swiftc -driver-print-jobs hasSuffix.swift

Result:

> .../swift/usr/bin/swift-autolink-extract /tmp/hasSuffix-d2b2b2.o -o /tmp/hasSuffix-f2d0a9.autolink
>
> /usr/bin/clang++ /tmp/hasSuffix-d2b2b2.o -L .../swift/usr/lib/swift/linux -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker .../swift/usr/lib/swift/linux -lswiftCore @/tmp/hasSuffix-f2d0a9.autolink -Xlinker -T .../swift/usr/lib/swift/linux/x86_64/swift.ld -o hasSuffix

So we can guess that these different compilation options are the reason why your simple script does not work with `swift`: somehow something is missing compared to when launched with other options.

As Apple say themselves in their blog, Open Source Swift is still very much a work in progress - a lot of components have yet to be implemented and a lot of bugs need to be fixed.